# Updating sequence of numbers (display order) using PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a int(11) `DisplayOrder` column in my database of slideshow items which tells my code what order to display the items in. An admin can update the order with a form, changing, for example, number 20 to number 3. Without forcing the user to manually find number 3 and swap it with 20, **is there an easy way to update the sequence of numbers in the database?** Either using MySQL, or changing items in in `array()` before sending a query.

I've searched and searched, and there doesn't seem to be many solid answers. The issue is that I currently have 400 rows, and that number will grow. I don't really want to have to do 400 updates every time the order changes. **Is there a better way?** Are there existing scripts?

Comment: It's easy to write yourself, but do you want to swap or insert and increase everything after the insert? You can also look at a client-side solution like jQuery sortable and rebuild the entire list on submit.

Comment: @jeroen Insert and increase everything after the insert. For example, if someone adds a new item to the slideshow, it will default go to the number 1 position. I will then have to increase every single row. Or insert an item into number 2, it will then have to increase everything after row 2.

Comment: If you want to increase all numbers that come after the new insert, I'm afraid the only way is updating all records after that one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to fully resequence the `DisplayOrder` values?

An `ORDER BY` clause will work just as well if there are duplicate values. To maintain a stable sort, you can order by a secondary column such as item name or id.

Comment: For most situations, `ORDER BY` on duplicate `DisplayOrder` values, and then a secondary sort on an auto-increment column (`ID`) would work (assume DESC). But, what about a situation where a lower `ID` has a duplicate `DisplayOrder` value as a higher `ID`, but the admin actually wants that lower `ID` displayed as the higher display order? It's probably rare, but this solution doesn't allow for that, as far as I can see.

Comment: Using your solution, since it seems to be the least resource intensive, here's what I'll do: add a `DisplayOrderSecondary` field which will be set to 1 upon INSERT, and I'll run a query which sets all other rows that have the same `DisplayOrder` number to have  `DisplayOrderSecondary = 0`. Then when pulling items from the DB, `ORDER BY DisplayOrder ASC, DisplayOrderSecondary DESC`, so the newest duplicate will always be displayed. Thanks!